# How to get network status changes with BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

When I change from wi-fi to 3g or vice versa the my AsyncTask will cause a error. So I want to trace this and restart the loading progress(or stop and proceed the asynctask if possible) when this happens. I looked it up on google and find that the BroadcastReceiver onReceive is called when this happens. The problem now is that I still don't get the exact moment when this happens.

Oncreate

```
    registerReceiver(mConnReceiver,new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

AsyncTask point of error(it's called on the HttpClient line):

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
    try
    {
        if(!isCancelled())//I have set this after I found the error
        {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        }
    }
```

The broadcastreceiver

```
private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        NetworkInfo changes = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        Log.w("current", "" + changes);
        if(noConnectivity)
        {
            task.cancel(true);
            task2.cancel(true);
            task3.cancel(true);
        }
        Log.w("taskIsCanceled","" + task.isCancelled());

    }
};
```

So I have two problems tracing the event of the error and restarting or stopping and proceeding the asynctaskes. I have 3 asynctaskes which take turns.

When I switch from 3g to wi-fi the noConnectivity boolean always returns that I have connection. While when I go from wi-fi to 3g it first returns that I dont and shortly after that I have(so that it connected).

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflections to monitor mobile data changes.

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getExtras() != null){
            final ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            boolean mobileDataEnabled = false;

            try{
                Class cmClass = Class.forName(mConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
                Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
                method.setAccessible(true); // Make the method callable
                mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean)method.invoke(mConnectivityManager);
            } catch(Exception e){
                return;
            }
            Toast.makeText(BackroundService.this, "Data state changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
    }

}
```

Comment: I get errors on the following : BackgroundService.this,MSG_NETWORK_STATE_MOBILE_CHANGED_TO_ON,MSG_NETWORK_STATE_MOBILE_CHANGED_TO_OFF can't resolve symbols. BackgroundService.this should that be my AsyncTask class?

Comment: Just remove that line :)